# Early stopping in Tensorflow using SessionRunHook() or validation monitor

Tags: tensorflow

I have a deep neural network which runs fine.  However, adding the following code to institute early stopping results in an error:

```
validation_metrics = {
"accuracy":
    tf.contrib.learn.MetricSpec(
        metric_fn=tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_accuracy,
        prediction_key=tf.contrib.learn.prediction_key.PredictionKey.
        CLASSES)}


validation_monitor = tf.contrib.learn.monitors.ValidationMonitor(
x=X_test, y=y_test, early_stopping_rounds=50, metrics=validation_metrics)
```

Output:

```
prediction_key=tf.contrib.learn.prediction_key.PredictionKey.CLASSES)}
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.learn' has no attribute 'prediction_key'
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail about what's going wrong, and see if you can reduce the size of the code sample needed to reproduce the error? That will help us better answer this.

Comment: Thank you - cut down on the code in the original question.  Full code gist [here](https://gist.github.com/KT12/7b081dfb776e8b0fde4d1275b980cc70)

Comment: what version of tensorflow and python are you using?

Comment: Python 3.6, TF '1.1.0-rc2' enabled for GPUs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
prediction_key=tf.contrib.learn.PredictionKey.CLASSES
```

Answer (score 0):

All monitors has been [deprecated](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7669#issuecomment-296532604).

Your best bet is to look at [training hooks](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/train#Training_Hooks). Only vanilla hooks are available as of this writing. So you will need to implement your [own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47137170/5307226).