# Early stopping with tf.estimator, how?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, tensorflow-estimator

I'm using `tf.estimator` in TensorFlow 1.4 and `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate` is great but I need early stopping. What's the prefered way of adding that?

I assume there is some `tf.train.SessionRunHook` somewhere for this. I saw that there was an old contrib package with a `ValidationMonitor` that seemed to have early stopping, but it doesn't seem to be around anymore in 1.4. Or will the preferred way in the future be to rely on `tf.keras` (with which early stopping is really easy) instead of `tf.estimator/tf.layers/tf.data`, perhaps?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Good news! `tf.estimator` now has early stopping support on master and it looks like it will be in 1.10.

```
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn, model_dir)

os.makedirs(estimator.eval_dir())  # TODO This should not be expected IMO.

early_stopping = tf.contrib.estimator.stop_if_no_decrease_hook(
    estimator,
    metric_name='loss',
    max_steps_without_decrease=1000,
    min_steps=100)

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(
    estimator,
    train_spec=tf.estimator.TrainSpec(train_input_fn, hooks=[early_stopping]),
    eval_spec=tf.estimator.EvalSpec(eval_input_fn))
```

Comment: This looked so promising, but appears as if it not in r1.9 (which I believe is the stable release as of today) ```>>> tf.contrib.estimator.stop_if_no_decrease_hook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.estimator' has no attribute 'stop_if_no_decrease_hook'```

Comment: I tried this with version 1.10 and I get the following error: `NotFoundError: Key signal_early_stopping/STOP not found in checkpoint
  [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]`

Comment: @TasosGlrs Are you sure you have not tried adding the hook and continuing from an existing checkpoint that has been created in an earlier run without the hook and hence missing the necessary keys?

Comment: @oens Yes, I create a new model dir every time I test it. I don't know if it's somehow relevant, but I create my estimator from a Keras model like this: `estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=my_model, model_dir='{0}/{1}/model_{2}'.format(def_modelpath, modeldir, my_model.name))`

Comment: I also had similar issue about the `signal_early_stopping not found`. Seems that is is because `early_stopping` hook can only be placed in TrainSpec hooks. For usage in EvalSpec hooks, this error would happen.

Comment: If you don't want to have bad surprises you may want to set `run_every_secs=None, run_every_steps=50`, otherwise your validation error will be only taken into account every 10 minutes or so.

Comment: Nice answer! Is specifying `min_steps` redundant here, since `min_steps < max_steps_without_decrease` anyway so there's no way the training will be stopped before `max_steps_without_decrease`?

Comment: Ah, just realized maybe it's *not* redundant? E.g. if min_steps=100 and max_steps_without_decrease=1000, it means that even if the best model from 0-1000 is at step=50, we would have to choose something greater than 100.

Answer (score 3):

First, you must name the loss to make it available to the early stopping call. If your loss variable is named "loss" in the estimator, the line

```
copyloss = tf.identity(loss, name="loss")
```

right beneath it will work.

Then, create a hook with this code.

```
class EarlyStopping(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
    def __init__(self,smoothing=.997,tolerance=.03):
        self.lowestloss=float("inf")
        self.currentsmoothedloss=-1
        self.tolerance=tolerance
        self.smoothing=smoothing
    def before_run(self, run_context):
        graph = ops.get_default_graph()
        #print(graph)
        self.lossop=graph.get_operation_by_name("loss")
        #print(self.lossop)
        #print(self.lossop.outputs)
        self.element = self.lossop.outputs[0]
        #print(self.element)
        return tf.train.SessionRunArgs([self.element])
    def after_run(self, run_context, run_values):
        loss=run_values.results[0]
        #print("loss "+str(loss))
        #print("running average "+str(self.currentsmoothedloss))
        #print("")
        if(self.currentsmoothedloss<0):
            self.currentsmoothedloss=loss*1.5
        self.currentsmoothedloss=self.currentsmoothedloss*self.smoothing+loss*(1-self.smoothing)
        if(self.currentsmoothedloss<self.lowestloss):
            self.lowestloss=self.currentsmoothedloss
        if(self.currentsmoothedloss>self.lowestloss+self.tolerance):
            run_context.request_stop()
            print("REQUESTED_STOP")
            raise ValueError('Model Stopping because loss is increasing from EarlyStopping hook')
```

this compares an exponentially smoothed loss validation with its lowest value, and if it is higher by tolerance, it stops training. If it stops too early, raising tolerance and smoothing will make it stop later. Keep smoothing below one, or it will never stop.

You can replace the logic in after_run with something else if you want to stop based on a different condition.

Now, add this hook to the evaluation spec. Your code should look something like this:

```
eval_spec=tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=lambda:eval_input_fn(batchsize),steps=100,hooks=[EarlyStopping()])#
```

Important note: The function, run_context.request_stop() is broken in the train_and_evaluate call, and doesn't stop training. So, I raised a value error to stop training. So you have to wrap the train_and_evaluate call in a try catch block like this:

```
try:
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(classifier,train_spec,eval_spec)
except ValueError as e:
    print("training stopped")
```

if you don't do this, the code will crash with an error when training stops.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do early stopping? If I understand your code correctly you're monitoring the training loss and not the validation loss.

Comment: This is attached to the EvalSpec, so it is monitoring validation loss. It will do early stopping if trained long enough. You may need to lower the smoothing value to .99 and lower tolerance if it isn't stopping fast enough.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is [`tf.train.StopAtStepHook`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/StopAtStepHook):

> This hook requests stop after either a number of steps have been executed or a last step has been reached. Only one of the two options can be specified.

You can also extend it and implement your own stopping strategy based on the step results.

```
class MyHook(session_run_hook.SessionRunHook):
  ...
  def after_run(self, run_context, run_values):
    if condition:
      run_context.request_stop()
```

Comment: tf.train.StopAtStepHook doesn't seem to do early stopping? But yeah, I guess I could do my own hook that evaluates a validation set, I just expected it to be builtin as of TensorFlow 1.4. Thanks!

Comment: @CarlThomé I see what you mean. You are right, tensorflow bundles only the trivial session hooks right now and recommends to plugin complex decisions with own hooks.

Comment: What variable will help me in capturing the loss in after_run function in each step to implement ealry stopping?

Answer (score 1):

Another option that doesn't use hooks is to create a `tf.contrib.learn.Experiment` (which seems, even though in contrib, to also support the new `tf.estimator.Estimator`).

Then train via the (apparently experimental) method `continuous_train_and_eval` with appropriately customized `continuous_eval_predicate_fn`.

According to the tensorflow docu, the `continuous_eval_predicate_fn` is

> A predicate function determining whether to continue eval after each iteration.

and called with the `eval_results` from the last evaluation run. For early stopping, use a customized function that keeps as state the current best result and a counter and returns `False` when the condition for early stopping is reached.

Note added: This approach would be use deprecated methods w/ tensorflow 1.7 (all of tf.contrib.learn is deprecated from that version onwards: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn )