# Tensorflow: Train estimator until convergence

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

As I understand the `Estimator` API, the method `train` train on the given data until the `input_fn` function raise an exception or until it reach the  number of steps. Therefore, if I want to loop until the estimator has *converged* (for some definition of it), I need to write the loop myself and test my criterion. Something like this, for an estimator `e` :

```
prevloss = 999999999999
while True:
    e.train(input_fn)
    loss = e.evaluate(input_fn)['loss']
    if abs(prevloss - loss) < 1e-4:
        break

    prevloss = loss
```

But there are a few things that are still obscure to me.

- When is the input function called? Should it always return the same data? What's its proper use?
- Will the data get uploaded to the GPU on every iteration?

  - If so, how can I avoid that?
- Is the data returned by the input function just embedded into the graph as constant?

  - If so, how do I make it *feedable*?
- Overall, it takes 0.8 second to start a tensorflow job (i.e. 1.6 seconds per iteration not making progress), wouldn't this loop better live on the GPU too?

  - If so, how do I do that?

Comment: You may refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47137061/early-stopping-with-tf-estimator-how) question for early stopping using Estimator API.