# Tensorflow Estimator Early Stopping hook parameters

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

Could anybody help explain how early stopping works with Tensorflow Estimator?

I'm using early stopping hook (see below), but it doesn't seem to do much - it doesn't stop, just trains for a given number epochs even when the model clearly overfits.

I would like to know how to set the **max_steps_without_decrease** and **min_steps** exactly. I'm used to setting patience parameter which instructs to stop training if loss (or other metric) on evaluation set hasn't improved for x number of epochs. I'm not sure how to map this to these new parameters - I have no intuition on how to set them.

```
early_stop = tf.contrib.estimator.stop_if_no_decrease_hook(estimator, 'loss', 1000)

train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=2000, hooks=[early_stop])

eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=eval_input_fn, steps=1, exporters=exporter)

exporter = tf.estimator.BestExporter(
        name="best_exporter",
        serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_fn,
        exports_to_keep=5
    )  

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(
            estimator,
            train_spec=train_spec,
            eval_spec=eval_spec)
```

Comment: Perhaps the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52641737/tensorflow-1-10-custom-estimator-early-stopping-with-train-and-evaluate/52642619#52642619) might be useful to understand how to use the hook

Comment: Yes, that's helpful. How do I know how many times evaluation is carried out: "Let's assume you're training indefinitely long having an evaluation every 1k steps" How do I know that evaluation is every 1k steps?

Comment: Is it "steps" option passed to tf.estimator.EvalSpec or "run_every_steps" option passed to tf.contrib.estimator.stop_if_no_decrease_hook?

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was wrong (I misread and understood something different). Since EvalSpec doesn't have a "run eval every X steps" the way to customize when eval runs is to save a checkpoint every 1k steps and setting the `throttle_secs` to 0 (see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17650)

Comment: `run_every_steps` only says how often the `should_stop` function is called. That function inspects previous eval results and potentially triggers the stop, but it doesn't *run* an eval.